# I need overflow x to follow the table as I scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table that is wider in some cases that what I want it to be. I have an scrollbar on the X axis so if its necessary you can use it to see the whole table.

However when there are a lot of records, more than 10 or so, you aren't able to see the scroll bar until you get to the bottom of the table. I need a scrollbar that stays at the end of the table but having the ending point as the bottom of what you see.

I'm attaching two pngs so you maybe can understand what I'm trying to say better, thanks in advice

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA9Rn.png)

[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2bJU.png)

Comment: In order to help you we need to see the HTML and CSS for the table - and any relevant JS, as that's been tagged too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your table in a div and set overflow-x to auto, so if the table is too large, it'll put a scroll bar on so the rest of the content can be seen. See the example below

**Edited** If you make the height fixed you can also add the y scroll bar.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height:50vh;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color:lightyellow;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a really wide and long table</td>
      <td>This is a really really really really wide table</td>
      <td>This is a really really really really wide table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a really really really really wide table</td>
      <td>This is a really really really really wide table</td>
      <td>This is a really really really really wide table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    
    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using a library, like the images in the question suggest, you may have to insert this div programmatically using js.

Comment: @adam that works but not the way I need, it creates a scroll bar at the bottom of the table but I still have to scroll all the way to the bottom to see it, I want to be able to see it at all times so I dont have to go to the bottom to see the things at the right if Im looking at a record thats is at the top, I dont know if I explained it well

Comment: @simon its just bootstrap 4

Comment: @danielo97ee that pagination and search looks suspiciously like https://bootstrap-table.com/

Comment: @Simon yes, it is, sorry for my mistake

Comment: I've edited it so you can see the x any y scroll bar so you don't need to go all the way to the bottom of the table to scroll. Is this more like what you're looking for?